# Implementing a html markup with PHP in OpenCart, How?

Tags: php, opencart

No PHP skills yet, I've just learned HTML/CSS and think I'm already good at it, but still not in PHP. I am developing my own OpenCart Store and also making it as my practice environment for html/css.

I've installed a paid module to make a product option as custom product field. I've already set it up but I am trying now to modify it to fit my needs.

Currently the custom module has this code (exerpt);

```
<?php foreach ($field['values'] as $value) { ?>
 <?php if ($value['selected'] && !$selected) { ?>
 <?php $selected = true; ?>
 <span><?php echo $field['name']; ?></span>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php if ($value['selected'] == $value['option_value_id']) { ?>
 <?php $checkbox_value .= $value['name'] . ', '; ?> 
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

The above code displays a custom field above the PRODUCT CODE field of the default theme, ie

**Tech Specs: Android Phone, Dual Core, 4.3 Inches Screen**

the comma is outputted by the code `', ';` in the code line 
 `<?php $checkbox_value .= $value['name'] . ', '; ?>`

I want to make it as un-ordered list and these code below is what I've got so far, base on trial and error only.

```
 <?php foreach ($field['values'] as $value) { ?>
 <?php if ($value['selected'] && !$selected) { ?>
 <?php $selected = true; ?>
 <span><?php echo $field['name']; ?></span>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php if ($value['selected'] == $value['option_value_id']) { ?><ul>
 <?php $checkbox_value .= $value['name'] . '</li><li>'; ?></li></ul>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

The code above displays the output like so;

**Tech Specs:**

Android Phone

- Dual Core
- 4.3 Inches Screen

But I like to output it like this

**Tech Specs:**

- Android Phone
- Dual Core
- 4.3 Inches Screen

**UPDATE:**

Need help to understand if, else and foreach
I am trying to modify the presentation. Each value is separated by comma (Android Phone, Dual Core, 4.3 Inches Screen) and the Option Name is Tech spec. I like to present the value as UL list. I almost done it, as shown above. Only thing is, Android Phone was not included.

My code looks like this when outputted;
[image]

UPDATE:

Output for dljve code...

[image]

Comment: i think it has nothing to do with your coding just go in backend and tick select android phone also for this particular product. or if you wana hardcode it you can add `</li>android phone<li>` after `<ul>`

Comment: BTW, did the author of that module give You the right to edit/modify his extension? The fact that You have bought a license does not automatically give You the rights to modify ones work.

Comment: @shadyyx. I'll check the documentation and I must do what is right. If the author does not permit, I shall abide.

Comment: I've read the documentation and license agreement. It's alright to modify.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<ul>` opening tag is not followed by `<li>`, thus displaying the first option not as a list element. You need to add `<li>` behind the `<ul>`.

I would also recommend cleaning up the code by echoing the HTML and reducing the `<?php` and `?>` tags to a minimum.

**EDIT:**

Ok, so what I think is happening (although I can't see the rest of the software's source) is that `$checkbox_value` is printed after this whole code, so the first and last `<ul>` and `<li>` tags would actually fall outside the list, which would produce the same error as you're seeing.

Could you try this code? This adds the `<ul>` `</ul>` tags to the `$checkbox_value` and adds the products surrounded in `<li>` `</li>` tags between them.

```
<?php
$checkbox_value .= "<ul>";
foreach ($field['values'] as $value)
{
    if ($value['selected'] && !$selected)
    {
        $selected = true;
        echo "<span>" . $field['name'] . "</span>";
    } 
    if ($value['selected'] == $value['option_value_id']) 
    {   
        $checkbox_value .= "<li>" . $value['name'] . "</li>";   
    } 
}
$checkbox_value .= "</ul>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've updated it not still not helping. Think I need to use FOREACH.

Comment: Hey @dljve... Your code worked, but Product Code and Stock also was indented.

Comment: The closing </ul> had enclosed the PRODUCT CODE and the AVAILABILITY. Thank you for the effort.I've checked the printed page and found out that PRODUCT CODE and the AVAILABILITY is also within <ul> </ul> tag.